# what is "FTS_0000000000002fe2_000000000000694c_INDEX_1.ibd" in mysql matador

Tags: mysql

i find lot's of ibd file in my mysql server datadir ,what is it ? mysql version is 5.7.12 , strange things is they are all no frm file

```
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  84M Aug 20 13:56 FTS_0000000000002fe2_000000000000694c_INDEX_1.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  12M Aug 20 13:55 FTS_0000000000002fe2_000000000000694c_INDEX_2.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 7.0M Aug 20 13:52 FTS_0000000000002fe2_000000000000694c_INDEX_3.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 496K Aug 20 13:52 FTS_0000000000002fe2_000000000000694c_INDEX_4.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 448K Aug 20 13:53 FTS_0000000000002fe2_000000000000694c_INDEX_5.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 7.0M Aug 20 13:55 FTS_0000000000002fe2_000000000000694c_INDEX_6.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  96K Aug 20 13:46 FTS_0000000000002fe2_BEING_DELETED_CACHE.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  96K Aug 20 13:46 FTS_0000000000002fe2_BEING_DELETED.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  96K Aug 20 13:56 FTS_0000000000002fe2_CONFIG.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  96K Aug 20 13:46 FTS_0000000000002fe2_DELETED_CACHE.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  96K Aug 20 13:46 FTS_0000000000002fe2_DELETED.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 396M Aug 21 20:59 FTS_000000000000304c_00000000000069eb_INDEX_1.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  40M Aug 21 20:58 FTS_000000000000304c_00000000000069eb_INDEX_2.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  11M Aug 21 20:58 FTS_000000000000304c_00000000000069eb_INDEX_3.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  10M Aug 21 20:58 FTS_000000000000304c_00000000000069eb_INDEX_4.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 9.0M Aug 21 20:58 FTS_000000000000304c_00000000000069eb_INDEX_5.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  10M Aug 21 20:58 FTS_000000000000304c_00000000000069eb_INDEX_6.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  96K Aug 21 20:32 FTS_000000000000304c_00000000000069f2_INDEX_1.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 848M Aug 21 20:59 FTS_000000000000304c_00000000000069f2_INDEX_2.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  96K Aug 21 20:32 FTS_000000000000304c_00000000000069f2_INDEX_3.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  96K Aug 21 20:32 FTS_000000000000304c_00000000000069f2_INDEX_4.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  96K Aug 21 20:32 FTS_000000000000304c_00000000000069f2_INDEX_5.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  96K Aug 21 20:32 FTS_000000000000304c_00000000000069f2_INDEX_6.ibd
```

and i check two of these file ,find some content , i can not know.

```
# strings FTS_0000000000003c97_BEING_DELETED_CACHE.ibd
infimum
supremum


# strings FTS_0000000000003c97_CONFIG.ibd
infimum
supremum
|cache_size_in_mb
1optimize_checkpoint_limit
Jsynced_doc_id
deleted_doc_count
!table_state
,use_stopword
```

Comment: These are files for InnoDB engine. For InnoDB , the data and the indexes are stored together in the .ibd file. You most likely don't have any table using ISAM engine. That is why,  you don't have any .frm file

Comment: i know it is InnoDB data file but i can not see any table like this ,why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The FTS_*.ibd files are the InnoDB FULLTEXT Search (FTS) index files**. [InnoDB introduced Full Text Searching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) from MySQL version 5.6 and onwards. They store only FTS indexing data. You possibly have some InnoDB table(s) with FTS defined on few field(s).

Indexing data is split up into 6 partitions. The `...INDEX_1.ibd` to `...INDEX_6.ibd` table files contain the FTS index data (6 parts).

**FTS_DELETED and FTS__DELETED_CACHE**

> Contain the document IDs (DOC_ID) for documents that are deleted but
>   whose data is not yet removed from the full-text index. The
>   FTS_DELETED_CACHE is the in-memory version of the FTS_DELETED
>   table.

**FTS__BEING_DELETED and FTS__BEING_DELETED_CACHE**

> Contain the document IDs (DOC_ID) for documents that are deleted and
>   whose data is currently in the process of being removed from the
>   full-text index. The FTS_BEING_DELETED_CACHE table is the in-memory
>   version of the FTS_BEING_DELETED table.

**FTS_CONFIG**

> Stores information about the internal state of the FULLTEXT index.

---

From MySQL 5.6.6 and higher, InnoDB engine enabled [`innodb_file_per_table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) approach. From [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html):

> Historically, InnoDB tables were stored in the system tablespace....
>   [Now] each InnoDB table is stored in its own tablespace data file (.ibd
>   file). This feature is controlled by the innodb_file_per_table
>   configuration option, which is enabled by default.

More from the docs:

> With innodb_file_per_table enabled, you can store InnoDB tables in a
>   tbl_name.ibd file. Unlike the MyISAM storage engine, with its separate
>   tbl_name.MYD and tbl_name.MYI files for indexes and data, InnoDB
>   stores the data and the indexes together in a single .ibd file. The
>   tbl_name.frm file is still created as usual.

Comment: i think this is not normal table ,because it is no .frm file

Comment: @user1208081 check the updated answer please. The FTS_*.ibd files are the InnoDB FULLTEXT index files. They store indexing data for the full text

Comment: the fulltext index preformance is not very well on version 5.7 ,right ?

Comment: @user1208081 It is recommended to use MyISAM for FTS, because it stores data in a compact fashion. However, if you have a specialized FTS need, I would ask you to use specialized database(s) for this like Apache SOLR; Elastic Search etc